# Why can't I create a .c .cpp file when creating a so file?

Tags: android-ndk

When building with Android.mk file below, an error occurs. I was wondering if I can't create a so file by binding .c and .cpp to LOCAL_SRC_FILES??

Android.mk
     ========

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libdecoder
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Decoder.c ima_adpcm.c Interface.c \
                   hevcWrapper.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../ffmpeg/ \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../ffmpeg/libavcodec \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../ffmpeg/libavformat \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../ffmpeg/libswscale

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lz -ljnigraphics -llog
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),arm64-v8a)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := D:/NDKandSDK_NEW/myToolChain/arm64/sysroot/usr/include $(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES)
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -Wl
else
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := D:/NDKandSDK_NEW/myToolChain/arm/sysroot/usr/include $(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES)
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -Wl,--no-warn-shared-textrel
endif
LOCAL_DISABLE_FATAL_LINKER_WARNINGS := true
LOCAL_CFLAGS := $(COMMON_CFLAGS) -fPIC
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libavformat libavcodec libswscale libavutil cpufeatures libswresample
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
$(call import-module,android/cpufeatures)
```

====================================================

```
[system.err]#include <version>
[system.err]^~~~~~~~~
[system.err]<VERSION>
[system.err]In file included from jni/Decoder/hevcWrapper.cpp:2:
[system.err]In file included from jni/Decoder/hevcParser/HevcParserImpl.h:9:
[system.err]In file included from D:/NDKandSDK_NEW/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\map:481:
[system.err] In file included from D:/NDKandSDK_NEW/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\__node_handle:16:
[system.err] In file included from D:/NDKandSDK_NEW/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\optional:159:
[system.err] jni/Decoder/../ffmpeg\version:1:1: error: expected unqualified-id
```

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libdecoder
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Decoder.c ima_adpcm.c Interface.c \
                  hevcWrapper.cpp \
                  hevcParser/BitstreamReader.cpp \
                  hevcParser/Hevc.cpp \
                  hevcParser/HevcParser.cpp \
                  hevcParser/HevcParserImpl.cpp \
                  hevcParser/HevcUtils.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../ffmpeg/ \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../ffmpeg/libavcodec \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../ffmpeg/libavformat \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../ffmpeg/libswscale

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lz -ljnigraphics -llog

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),arm64-v8a)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := D:/NDKandSDK_NEW/myToolChain/arm64/sysroot/usr/include $(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES)
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -Wl
else
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := D:/NDKandSDK_NEW/myToolChain/arm/sysroot/usr/include $(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES)
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -Wl,--no-warn-shared-textrel
endif
LOCAL_DISABLE_FATAL_LINKER_WARNINGS := true
LOCAL_CFLAGS := $(COMMON_CFLAGS) -fPIC
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fPIC -std=c++11
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libavformat libavcodec libswscale libavutil cpufeatures libswresample
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
```

---

```
[system.err] 4.2
[system.err] ^
[system.err] In file included from jni/Decoder/hevcWrapper.cpp:2:
[system.err] In file included from jni/Decoder/hevcParser/HevcParserImpl.h:9:
[system.err] D:/NDKandSDK_NEW/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\map:488:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<VERSION>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
[system.err] #include <version>
[system.err] ^~~~~~~~~
[system.err]<VERSION>
[system.err] In file included from jni/Decoder/hevcWrapper.cpp:2:
[system.err] In file included from jni/Decoder/hevcParser/HevcParserImpl.h:9:
[system.err] In file included from D:/NDKandSDK_NEW/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\map:488:
[system.err] jni/Decoder/../ffmpeg\version:1:1: error: expected unqualified-id
[system.err] 4.2
[system.err] ^
[system.err] In file included from jni/Decoder/hevcWrapper.cpp:2:
[system.err] In file included from jni/Decoder/hevcParser/HevcParserImpl.h:10:
[system.err] D:/NDKandSDK_NEW/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\list:189:10: warning: non-portable path to file '<VERSION>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
[system.err] #include <version>
[system.err]^~~~~~~~~
[system.err]<VERSION>
[system.err] In file included from jni/Decoder/hevcWrapper.cpp:2:
[system.err] In file included from jni/Decoder/hevcParser/HevcParserImpl.h:10:
[system.err] In file included from D:/NDKandSDK_NEW/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\list:189
[system.err]jni/Decoder/../ffmpeg\version:1:1: error: expected unqualified 
[system.err]4.2
[system.err]^
[system.err]jni/Decoder/hevcWrapper.cpp:4:46: error: brackets are not allowed here; to declare an array, place the brackets after the name
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug in either ffmpeg or your Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../ffmpeg/
```

You're adding the root of the ffmpeg source tree to your include path here.

```
[system.err] jni/Decoder/../ffmpeg\version:1:1: error: expected unqualified-id
```

That directory contains a file named "version" that collides with the C++ standard library header: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/version

If that directory doesn't need to be on the include path, don't add it to `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES`. This isn't the first project I've seen with this problem (it's also a problem for jsoncpp), and in that case it *was* actually a required include directory. If that's the case then you need to delete or rename the file named version because it cannot be present in a C++ project (this header is new as of C++20, but all of the C++ library headers include it transitively).